# Compare rows with conditions

Tags: sql, compare, rows

I am looking for a way to compare rows in a table:

Example 1

```
ID        StartDate     TerminationDate
1         01.01.2010    NULL
1         01.01.2011    NULL
1         05.01.2011    NULL        
1         01.01.2017    NULL     
2         01.01.2010   31.12.2010
2         01.01.2011   NULL
2         05.01.2011   NULL         
2         01.01.2017   NULL 
3         01.01.2010   31.12.2011
3         01.01.2011   31.12.2011
3         05.01.2011   NULL
3         01.01.2017   NULL 
4         01.01.2010   31.12.2011
4         01.01.2011   31.12.2011
4         05.01.2015   NULL
4         01.01.2017   NULL
```

Result:

```
ID        StartDate     
1         01.01.2010  
2         01.01.2011
3         01.01.2010
4         05.01.2015
```

If no TerminationDate is given for an ID, I would like to display the minimum of StartDate. In this case 01.01.2010.

For ID 2 however, there is a TerminationDate given. In this case I need to check, if the second StartDate > first TerminationDate (01.01.2011 > 31.12.2010). If second StartDate > first TerminationDate and second TerminationDate is either Null or > third StartDate, then I want to display 01.01.2011. Otherwise I would check the next StartDate in the same manner.

The ID can be seen as an client an every row stand for an contract. As long as at least one contract is consists, I want the first StartDate. ID 4 would be an example of where no contract was in place between 31.11.2011 and 05.01.2015. Therefore the minimum StartDate is 05.01.2015.

I hope you get the idea behind my question. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the first half of your solution using a GROUP BY and COALESCE.  Hopefully it's enough to get you started.

```
        SELECT
            [id],
            [NewDate] = COALESCE(date1, MIN(date2))
        FROM
            TheTable
        GROUP BY
            [id]
        ORDER BY
            [id]
```

Comment: I edited my first post because it seems to me that it wasn't 100% clear what I am looking for.